# Hibernate JPA: Why is SQL executed?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

Is there a good way to determine why Hibernate/JPA performs a query. I have two entities linked by

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST},
          fetch   = FetchType.LAZY)
```

When fetching one entity, the other one is also queried. I am trying to find out how to avoid that (actual lazy loading).

Thanks,

-dennis

Comment: How do you know that the other is queried? Could copy your query here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `FetchType.LAZY` is a hint for persistence provider, provider is not required to follow it.

Perhaps in this case provider have to check whether relationship is `null` (otherwise provider can create a proxy object for lazy access to the entity).

You can try the following:

- If this relationship is never `null`, mark it as `optional = false`
- If you use field access (i.e. annotation is placed on the field), try to use property access

Answer (score 0):

`Enum FetchType` defines strategies for fetching data from the database. The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime that data must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime that data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed. **The implementation is permitted to eagerly fetch data for which the LAZY strategy hint has been specified**.

[Enum FetchType](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html)